# How automate setting default Name (general page), Host Name/address, Username, Pass(connection page) creating server in pgadmin4 using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, pgadmin-4

I am beginner in docker. I want to automate process for my teammates.

1. How can I set default labels for Name, Host Name/address, Username, Password in pgAdmin4 via docker-compose? Or probably I have to use Dockerfile?

   [image]
2. How can I automate connection pgAdmin4 to the db server via docker-compose or docker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can export the saved servers to a servers.json file (https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.5/import_export_servers.html#json-format) and then map the file in docker-compose(https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.5/container_deployment.html - PGADMIN_SERVER_JSON_FILE)